# Trying to solve flex2gateway issue (Flex /ColdFusion 9 Enterprise on VPS Windows Server)

Tags: apache-flex, coldfusion, remoting, windows-server

I'm migrating a Flex 3/ColdFusion 7 app over to ColdFusion 9 Enterprise. I'm getting a strange result: When a user first visits the application, I receive the following error:

> faultCode:Client.Error.MessageSend faultString:'Send failed' faultDetail:'Channel.Connect.Failed error Invalid URL url: 'http://[mydomain]/flex2gateway/'

The weird thing is the error goes away if you refresh the browser. It will however reappear if you restart the browser. I have no clue as to what is going on. I did go directly to the 'http://[mydomain]/flex2gateway' and saw the request blank white page. I took a look at the logs in CFAdmin but nothing there. Wondering if it has to do with how ColdFusion and Windows Server are communicating. I did learn of a workaround here:

http://forums.adobe.com/thread/662371

I'd prefer not use a hack. Any ideas on how to solve this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Jason

Comment: Sounds like a session that isn't yet initialized on the first call. I lack information to really help you though. Could you see what's being sent back and forth on that first call by using a proxy (like [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/)) and post that?

Comment: Are you dynamically configuring the Channel in Flex? Maybe you're doing a first call while the Channel is not yet defined... after the 1st start it's okay as it's "stored" in a session or any other alike variable.